# Pushing to session overrides data?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to build a multi step upload form, storing data in the session. On my controller I use:

`$request->session()->push('upload', $request->all());`

This store the first data from the first page of the form.

I then run the method again, calling the same line above again.

But the data is being overridden. I thought if you pushed it would be added to the `upload` session data from step one.

How can I continue to push data from each of the forms steps to the session?

Comment: wow, very strange I tried this myself and I got the same thing as you (it didnt persist). However after placing some debug statements in the `push` function, and removing those again, it now works as it should wtf

Comment: Hmm i might have a hunch: are you sure you didnt `die;` or `dd()` somewhere? That mightve caused the bug in my test case also. The data probably isnt persisted properly if you dont complete the request.

Comment: Could you post your code, I still cant get this to work - storing it as a single array.

Comment: simply `session()->push('x', 'y');` and next line `dump(session()->get('x'));` then continue with the request

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question, if you check my example, I'm saving an array

Comment: idk i cant reproduce the issue anymore. It shouldnt matter what the second parameter is, it should add a new element to that `'x'` array.

Comment: It doesnt add new elemets to the array, it creates a new array.